# Using HTTPS with BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service)

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, ssl, iis-6, https

I am writing a client application that needs to send a file via BITS to my server. I have everything working for the most part, but I can't get the BITS connection to operate securely with HTTPS.

Right now I'm just using basic authentication through HTTP, so the login is being sent cleartext--which is not optimal :-) I would like to be able to use HTTPS, but am not sure how to go about doing this. According to this Google Groups thread, BITS "doesn't support authentication using certificates" (though that comment is a few years old now). Does this mean SSL is out? How else can I secure a connection for BITS via HTTPS?

My server is running IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(I originally posted this at Stack Overflow, but thought I would try here as well--seems to fall under both domains)

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362781(VS.85).aspx)

> **Using Certificates for Client/Server
> Authentication**
>
> In secure client/server
> communication, clients and servers can
> use digital certificates to mutually
> authenticate each other. BITS
> automatically supports
> certificate-based server
> authentication for secure HTTP
> transports. To provide BITS the client
> certificate needed for mutual
> authentication, call either the

```
IBackgroundCopyJobHttpOptions::SetClientCertificateByID
```

> or

```
IBackgroundCopyJobHttpOptions::SetClientCertificateByName
```

> method.
>
> When a web site accepts but does not
> require an SSL client certificate, and
> the BITS job does not specify a client
> certificate, the job will fail with
> ERROR_WINHTTP_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED
> (0x80072f0c).